# Under which conditions caching of a page(not web caching) should not be allowed?

Tags: caching

I would like to know in what ways,using a cache buffer(eg.TLB) to cache frequent pages would be not advantageous or potentially catastrophic.
I searched a bit but could not comprehend this:

"When that page is shared with another process running on a different core of the machine. For example, in Intel 3rd generation core architecture (Ivybridge)  `L1` and `L2` cores are private for a core and `L3` is shared. So, a shared page must not go above `L3` cache or otherwise explicit coherence mechanism must be done by the programmer "

Comment: Where did you find that? Do you have URL? I don't think it's programmer's task to care for CPU L3 cache coherence.

Comment: Here is the link--(http://gateoverflow.in/10430/in-which-conditions-you-will-not-allow-a-page-to-cached).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are asking about x86 CPU caches or generally for any architecture.

As far as I know (and I didn't find any source saying otherwise), in x86, the CPU hardware always ensures that you have a cache-coherent shared memory. So you as an application or OS programmer don't need to care about this. Also there is no instruction which would allow you to deny the CPU from caching your data in L1/L2 or L3 cache. This wouldn't make any sense, as for every write the CPUs must ensure shared cache is coherent and it wouldn't know about your single non-cacheable page. Although it seems there are ways to pre-fetch some data into cache if needed.

For other (theoretical and future) architectures, it is possible to present the cache (and hence whole memory) as not coherent - then the OS must be written so that it will ensure memory coherence itself. For example [this paper](http://sigops.org/sosp/sosp11/posters/summaries/sosp11-final7.pdf) writes about OS design for non-cache-coherent systems (like Intel's experimental *Single-Chip Cloud computer*).

For writing applications "friendly" to caching, there are many good questions and answers also here in SO, few of them mentioning this 114-pdf from RedHat: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf). Here is also Wikipedia page for [Cache Coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence).

Comment: This was asked in the interview i gave recently,and my immediate response was "why would one wan't to do that" but the interviewer wanted me to think of any possible scenarios in which it would need to be done.By the way,the interview was supposed to be for a freshman.

Comment: The purpose of that question in interview was probably to see how you can think of problems and give ideas, not to come with any definitive solution.